# PostgreSQL different versions

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm new with PostgreSQL and want to start working with it as the database for a web development.
But on PostgreSQL website I have 4 active versions: 9.2, 9.1, 9.0 and 8.4.

Why does PostgreSQL have 4 active versions?
What are the main differences between them?
Should I go for the latest one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I disagree re the off-topic vote; perfectly reasonable here IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Active** in this context means that they're still being maintained; bug fixes, security fixes.  Things that go end of life/fall out of support are not listed any more.  That's about it.

You can learn more by reading the [version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) document.

And yes, going for the newest if you have no legacy stuff that may break is a fairly safe option.

Comment: Added a link to the version policy, which explains in detail. Basically: Run the latest version. The maintained older major releases are for people who don't want to upgrade because they don't want to do the app testing required (some major releases are imperfectly compatible with each other).

Comment: Thanks Craig! Will remember that in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I was asking this because I read somewhere that 9.2 has less performance in some queries than 9.1. But, don't know if that is true or if is already fixed in recent builds.